# Alert an attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print the attribute of `isChecked`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction(){
    alert(document.getElementById('myId').isChecked);
}
</script>
    </head>
<body>

<img id="myId" isChecked="0"/>
<br>
<button  onclick="myFunction();">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

it prints me `undefined`

any help appreciated!

Comment: How is a guy with 1k karma asking a question asnewered by simple google search? Just google: javascript html element attribute

Comment: @aledujke Karma also increments due to questions ;)

Comment: All aboard the karma train!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [getAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp)

```
alert(document.getElementById('myId').getAttribute("isChecked"));
```

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
alert(document.getElementById('myId').getAttribute("isChecked"));
```

Comment: Really? Three minutes after somebody else posted the same answer, and two minutes after a second person did?

Comment: @nnnnnn - During i open the question, there were no answers. I just forget to refresh my page before posting the answer. Is this a big mistake!!!

Comment: No, we've all done that. But it wouldn't be inappropriate to delete the answer once you realise it is identical to an earlier one... Unless of course you offer additional information (but then it wouldn't be identical).